# Constructing an emoticon in HTML5 canvas for school project

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, drawing

I am attempting to construct an animated emoticon for a school project. First and foremost, the canvas is giving me issues just even starting with a yellow circle with a black outline. I have yet to even start with the face or any animation. I have searched the internet as well as this site for advice with constructing a circle with the arc and have yet to be successful. Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js ></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas width="1200" height="900" id="myCanvas">
      Your browser does not support canvas.
  </canvas>
  <script>
        var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.beginpath(); 
        ctx.strokeStyle = "000000";
        ctx.fillstyle = "FFFF00";
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.arc(600, 450, 300, 0, Math.Pi * 2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have taken this code and added and subtracted lines. I have changed the order, and even put the code in different parts of the program, specifically the canvas script in the head. Nothing has worked. What am I doing wrong? Does anyone have suggestions for this, the emoticon, or the animation?

Comment: `Math.PI` not `Math.Pi`

Comment: Make sure to use developer tools of your chosen browser to watch the console for errors when you work on projects, so you'll see the message: "Uncaught TypeError: ctx.beginpath is not a function"

Comment: That is good advice thank you. I was not aware that it was to be Math.PI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to NOBrien's answer, you also want to set the `fillStyle`, not fillstyle.

This was a bit of a learning experience for me as well, so I sort of threw in a bunch of stuff to it:

https://jsfiddle.net/gregborbonus/o67bdr0m/

Comment: What is the best way to animate this image to make it wink? Use the frame animation?

Answer (score 1):

You have two typos - It should be ctx.beginPath()  (capital P) and Math.PI (capital I):

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath(); 
ctx.strokeStyle = "000000";
ctx.fillStyle = "FFFF00";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.arc(600, 450, 300, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. The other issue I'm still encountering is the fill style ends up being the default, or black, whereas I coded the fill to be yellow. I noticed the syntax should be fillStyle instead of fillstyle but that does not fix the issue.